# Vue Element UI Select Option Bug

Tags: vue.js, html-select, element-ui

### Element UI

I have fetch the data from backend and use it as select option which does not come with value object, but
when I try to select any item in select option, the select option show all item list selected, but the model value is correct

Follow Code Fetch the Bug

```
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :key="item.key"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item">
    </el-option>
```

This was the Sample Bug I created...
https://codepen.io/JackarooNg/pen/qBRdqgO

Comment: if you want your v-model value to be object's value then use :value="item.value" else everything looks fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `model` name is matched with `select option`'s property of `key` and `label`

Step 1: `Script` will be like

```
<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      visible: false,
      options: [
        {
          value: "Option1",
          label: "Option1"
        },
        {
          value: "Option2",
          label: "Option2"
        },
        {
          value: "Option3",
          label: "Option3"
        }
      ],
      options1: [
        {
          value: "Option1",
          label: "Option1"
        },
        {
          value: "Option2",
          label: "Option2"
        },
        {
          value: "Option3",
          label: "Option3"
        }
      ],
      value: "",
      value1: ""
    };
  }
});
```

Step 2: `HTML` template will be

```
<div id="app">
  <el-button @click="visible = true">Button</el-button>
  <el-dialog :visible.sync="visible" title="Hello world">
    <p>Try Element</p>
  </el-dialog>
  <el-select v-model="value" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item"
    >
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
  {{value}}
  <el-select v-model="value1" placeholder="Select">
    <el-option
      v-for="item in options1"
      :key="item.value"
      :label="item.label"
      :value="item"
    >
    </el-option>
  </el-select>
  {{value1}}
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-kepler-g0bxf)